# Javascript dynamic Regexp value

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanting to pass in a dynamic value for this regex but it's not working. I'm not sure what's missing from my code. I tried to escape the string but for some reason I missing something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var r = new RegExp('(?:^| )(myclass)(?: |$)'), m = (""+n.className).match(r); //found

var c = 'myclass';
var r = new RegExp("(?:^| )('\\b'" + c + "'\\b')(?: |$)"), m = (""+n.className).match(r); // not found
```

Edit --- when adding dynamic value (myclass) no node is returned. When it's hard coded I can find a node without issue.

```
 var n = document.getElementById('parentID');
 var c = 'myclass';

function find(n,c) {

do {
    if (typeof n.className !== 'undefined') {
        var r = new RegExp("(?:^| )(myclass)(?: |$)"), m = (""+n.className).match(r);
        if (m !== null) {
            n.setAttribute("id", "current");
        }
    }
    if (n.hasChildNodes()) {
        finds(n.firstChild)
    }
}
while (n = n.nextSibling)
}
```

Comment: it's an element = var n= document.getElementById('someDiv');

Comment: thats okay but what is the value of n.classname? is it some string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
var c = 'myclass';
var r = new RegExp("(?:^| )(\\b"+c+"\\b)(?: |$)");
console.log(r);
```

this will return the result as

```
RegExp /(?:^| )('\b'myclass'\b')(?: |$)/
```

suppose you dont want the `\b` on both sides of `myclass` then just use the code below :

```
var c = 'myclass';
var r = new RegExp("(?:^| )("+c+")(?: |$)");
console.log(r);
```

go ahead , fire your firebug, paste in it and hit <kbd>Run</kbd>

**update**

check this code its working:

```
var c = 'myclass';
var r = new RegExp("(?:^| )(\\b"+c+"\\b)(?: |$)");
console.log(r);

var str = "myclass";
var m = (""+str).match(r);
console.log(m);
```

Comment: @user686483 what output are you expecting ?? can you give an example

Comment: Hi @aelor: I'm using this in a re-usable js function: 
function find(n,c) {

 do {
  if (typeof n.className !== 'undefined') {
   var r = new RegExp("(?:^| )(myclass)(?: |$)"), m = (""+n.className).match(r);
   if (m !== null) {
    n.setAttribute("id", "current");
   }
  }
  if (n.hasChildNodes()) {
   finds(n.firstChild)
  }
 }
 while (n = n.nextSibling)
}

Answer (score 1):

In the failing RegExp, you need to remove the single quotes around `'\\b'` I think.

EDIT: Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/UqL4J/ seems to suggest that your regexp with the single quotes removed does work as expected.

Comment: I did try this as well as many other combinations. It's something very simple I know but I just can't get the syntax right.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a fiddle that I hope is relevant.

Comment: Hi Peter, I've verified it's working but now my function is returning #text as a node as apposed to <div class="myclass"> </div> which is what it was returning with the hardcoded value originally. So two different issues here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you need to be adding the characters before and after where you add the value into the regex (`'\\b'`). Try using the line

`var r = new RegExp("(?:^| )(" + c + ")(?: |$)"), m = (""+n.className).match(r);`

which will expand to

`(?:^| )(myclass)(?: |$)`

which is the same as the first RegEx line.

Comment: I tried this but it's failing for some reason. If I have "(?:^| )(" + c + ")(?: |$)" it fails but if I have "(?:^| )(myclass)(?: |$)" it's fine.

Comment: @user686483 If you extract the string from the constructor and print it, what is the output?